# Can I combine device category with hit-level metrics in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm querying the Google Analytics API, and got a question about combining different dimension and metric scopes. Is it possible to combine a user-level dimension like "Device Category" with a hit-level metric, i.e. "Unique Pageviews"?

I know I can't combine hit-level dimensions like "Page" with session-level metrics like "Sessions". But I can't seem to find any documentation of other combinations.

My gut tells me it should be possible as user-level dimensions are stored in a cookie and then be associated with each hit. But I'd really like to get a second opinion on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify valid combinations of dimensions and metrics with **Dimensions & Metrics Explorer** tool:

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

Since not all dimensions and metrics can be queried together, with this tool you can select a dimension or metric checkbox to see all the other values that can be combined in the same query.

**[EDIT]**

If your request is which dimensions and metrics may be misleading when combining, the answer is... depends on the result you want to obtain and on knowing how to recognize the data. If you want to know which pages are most viewed when a user lands in a specific landing page, you can do this by querying landing pages dimension and page dimension. You will have repeated the landing page many times in the reports (many times how many pages have been viewed from sessions originating in that landing) but this does not mean that it is wrong. Sure depending on what you combine you can get a misleading result, but Google Analytics cannot know if it is misleading for you or if you wanted to do it.

Comment: I've tried using the Dimensions & metrics explorer but find it too generous. It only shows what can be combined in a query but not which dimensions and metrics that may be misleading when combining. 

For instance, accordning to the tool it's totally legit to combine Sessions and Page. But in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033861?hl=en) it says that "Sessions is a session-based metric so it can only be used with session-level dimensions like Source or City. It would not be logical to combine Sessions with a hit-level dimension like Page."